# How do I determine scope in an XMLHttp callback function

Tags: javascript, scope, xmlhttprequest

I'm learning to use XMLHttp to fetch information, and I can't figure out the scope within the functions.  This is my code:

```
<p id="demo">

<script>
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      results =  this.responseText;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = results;
    }
    
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "my_file.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
  </script>
```

It populates "demo"'s innerHTML correctly, but I'm trying to get the contents of "results" available outside the callback function. Nothing I've tried so far has worked.  I've tried declaring it just above the XMLHttp declaration, thinking it would be global, but's not.  I've even tried setting the innerHTML of p and then setting "results" with the innerHTML of "demo". Nothing works.  I just can't get my head wrapped around the scoping rules.

Comment: It should work in code that runs after the response has been received. Put it in a button's click handler, for instance.

Comment: The scope is global since you don't have a `var` or `let` declaration for the variable.

Comment: I do want it to be global.  What is the flow of the program here?  Let's wrap the whole thing in a button.

Comment: It IS global. The problem isn't scope, it's timing. Since XMLHttpRequest is asynchronous, the updated value isn't available immediately.

Comment: Add `button.addEventListener("click", () => console.log(results))` and you'll see the value when you click on the button.

Comment: I did notice the timing issue, but I guess I didn't realize its full implications.  I created console.log outputs at various points in my code, and noticed that instead of firing in order, they wrote in 1 - 3 - 2 order, "3" being where I thought the output would be.

I'll revisit this tonight and report back.

Comment: Exactly. `xhttp.send()` returns immediately, it doesn't wait for the response. So anything you do immediately after that will not wait for the variable to be updated. This is all explained in the duplicate question.